# How can I call a stored procedure using Asterisk MYSQL command?

Tags: mysql, asterisk

I have a stored procedure. It has two output parameters. How can I call it using Asterisk MYSQL command? When I use this command I don't get any result:

```
exten => s,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} CALL RemainingTime(${WeekID}, @rDay, @rHour)\;SELECT @rDay, @rHour\;)
exten => s,n,MYSQL(Fetch foundRow ${resultid} remainingDay remainingHour)
exten =>s,n,NoOp(${remainingDay})
exten =>s,n,NoOp(${remainingHour})
```

remainingDay and remainingHour are empty;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function instead of procedure.

If need return more then 1 value, I usually use something like concat(a,':',b).

Also it is recommended use func_odbc instead of mysql. It have much more options and setup connection pool automatically.
Command MySQL deprecated and will be removed in future versions.